# Dropdown link doesn't work on IOS devices

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I recently developped my first webapp as a junior dev, and I am facing a problem that I never heard about before.

I have a navbar with a dropdown menu. When I click on it with a desktop or an Android device, everything works well. BUT, it doesn't work of IOS device (I've tried on Iphone 12 and X, on Chrome and Safari).

I am using a Tailwindcss dropdown component as so :

```html
<style>
  .dropdown:focus-within .dropdown-menu {
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(0) scale(1);
    visibility: visible;
  }
</style>

<!-- Navbar / logo -->

<div class="navbar w-screen flex justify-between items-center shadow-lg sticky top-0 bg-white pb-2 z-50">
  <div class="navbar-left px-4">
    <div class="navbar-logo">
      <a class="logo" id="logo" href="/">
        <img class="h-12 md:h-16" src=" <%= image_url("PSB_logo_associations.png") %> " />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Navbar / User -->

<div class="navbar-right bg-transparent flex flex-col justify-center">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
  <ul class="hidden md:flex">
    <%= link_to "Events", events_path, class: "font-base text-psb border-b-4 border-transparent hover:border-rose mx-4 pt-2 pb-0" %>
    <%= link_to "Associations", assos_path, class: "font-base text-psb border-b-4 border-transparent hover:border-rose mx-4 pt-2 pb-0" %>
    <% if current_user&.admin? || (current_user && current_user.asso_members.where(admin_asso: true).any?) %>
      <%= link_to 'Add asso member', new_asso_member_path, class: "font-base text-psb border-b-4 border-transparent hover:border-rose mx-4 pt-2 pb-0" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "News", articles_path, class: "font-base text-psb border-b-4 border-transparent hover:border-rose mx-4 pt-2 pb-0" %>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to current_user.first_name, profile_path, class: "font-base text-psb border-b-4 border-transparent hover:border-rose mx-4 pt-2 pb-0" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, class: "font-base text-psb border-b-4 border-transparent hover:border-rose mx-4 pt-2 pb-0"  %>
        <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, class: "font-base text-psb border-b-4 border-transparent hover:border-rose mx-4 pt-2 pb-0" %>
      <% end %>
  </ul>

  <!-- DROPDOWN -->
    <div class=" relative inline-block text-left dropdown">
      <span class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
        <button class="inline-flex justify-center items-center w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-psb transition duration-150 ease-in-out bg-white hover:text-psb-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue active:bg-psb-50 active:text-psb-800"
         type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="headlessui-menu-items-117">

         <!-- Chevron -->
         <svg class="md:hidden h-4 px-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
           <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7" />
          </svg>

          <span>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <%= image_tag user_signed_in? ? current_user.avatar_if_present : 'avatar-auto.svg', class: "rounded-full h-12 w-12 object-cover lg:h-14 lg:w-14" %>
            <% end %>
          </span>
        </button>
      </span>
      <div class="opacity-0 invisible dropdown-menu transition-all duration-300 transform origin-top-right -translate-y-2 scale-95">
        <div class="absolute right-0 w-56 mt-2 origin-top-right bg-white border border-psb-200 divide-y divide-psb-100 rounded-md shadow-lg outline-none" aria-labelledby="headlessui-menu-button-1" id="headlessui-menu-items-117" role="menu">
          <div class="px-4 py-3 md:hidden">
            <p class="text-sm leading-5">Signed in as</p>
            <p class="text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-psb-900 truncate">
              <%= user_signed_in? ? current_user.first_name : '-' %>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="py-1 md:hidden">
            <p href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="0" class="text-psb flex justify-between w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-left hover:bg-rose-200"  role="menuitem" >
              <%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path  %>
            </p>
            <p href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="1" class="text-psb flex justify-between w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-left hover:bg-rose-200"  role="menuitem" >
              <%= link_to 'Events', events_path  %>
            </p>
            <p href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="1" class="text-psb flex justify-between w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-left hover:bg-rose-200"  role="menuitem" >
              <%= link_to 'Associations', assos_path %>
            </p>
            <p href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="2" class="text-psb flex justify-between w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-left hover:bg-rose-200" role="menuitem" >
              <%= link_to "News", articles_path %>
            </p>
          </div>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <div class="py-1">
            <p href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="3" class="text-psb flex justify-between w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-left hover:bg-rose-200"  role="menuitem" >
              <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
            </p>
          </div>
          <% else %>
          <div class="py-1 md:hidden">
            <p href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="3" class="text-psb flex justify-between w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-left hover:bg-rose-200"  role="menuitem" >
              <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="py-1 md:hidden">
            <p href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="3" class="text-psb flex justify-between w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-left hover:bg-rose-200"  role="menuitem" >
              <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %>
            </p>
          </div>

          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Any idea of what's happening and how I can fix this ?

Comment: `Any idea of what's happening and how I can fix this ?` no, because you need to post enough relevant information here for people to help. post reproducible code samples

Comment: Where is the click breaking, on the initial nav bar click or on the menu item click?  Is there additional Javascript that should be posted as well?